# Optimise/compress images uploaded with refile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-compression, image-optimization, refile

Is there a way to optimise images uploaded with refile? I use a CDN so the files are mostly just created once, but i would like them to be optimised to save bandwidth.

I use Mini Magick for image manipulation, but can this also be used to reduce file size / Optimise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying tools that handle image manipulation are from [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick). Image manipulation functionality has been extracted out of Refile into a separate gem, [refile-mini_magick](https://github.com/refile/refile-mini_magick). You should be able to write your own processor as described in the [readme](https://github.com/refile/refile#processing).

Maybe something like this:

```
def quality(percentage)
  manipulate! do |img|
    unless img.quality == percentage
      img.write(current_path) do
        self.quality = percentage
      end
    end

    img = yield(img) if block_given?
    img
  end
end
```

Comment: how do i add this? I have tried putting it in a libfile, but that gets me nowhere: